# AzureDevOps yaml template - expression as parameter default value

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I want to have an expression as a default value for a parameter but I get "a template expression is not allowed in this context"
Since templates cannot have variables unless they ONLY have variables (another thing I don't get...), I am looking for other alternatives. Anyone has any idea?

What I'm trying is this:

```
parameters:
  - name: paramOne
    default: ${{ lower(replace('$(System.TeamProject)',' ','')) }}
    type: string
```

## EDIT

Here's a full example. This is azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- template: test-template.yml
```

This is test-template.yml:

```
parameters:
  - name: paramOne
    default: ${{ lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ','')) }}
    type: string
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Run PowerShell script"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: Write-Host "${{parameters.paramOne}}"
```

This results in the error:
"a template expression is not allowed in this context"

Variables cannot be added to test-template.yml, as indicated here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse
"If you are using a template to include variables in a pipeline, the included template can only be used to define variables"

Comment: have you tried to use `${{ lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ','')) }}`?

Comment: yes, same result. The issue is not with the variable but with the usage of an expression in the default value.

Comment: The documentation has an approach to "Conditionally assign a variable": 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-assign-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, then I would propose the following workaround

```
parameters:
  - name: paramOne
    displayName: 'My param. Leave empty to populate with default value (project name). bla bla...'
    default: ''
    type: string

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  name: 'setVar'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      if( "${{ parameters.paramOne }}" -eq "") {
        $val = "$(System.TeamProject)".ToLower().Replace(" ","")
      } else {
        $val = "${{ parameters.paramOne }}"
      }
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=varOne]$val"
```

and from there on use `varOne` instead of `paramOne`

Comment: The problem is that if you put variables in a template, the template can only have variables and nothing else - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#variable-reuse - " If you are using a template to include variables in a pipeline, the included template can only be used to define variables"

Comment: I'm not sure what limitation you mean, i.e. what does not work here for you? I have used the above many times

Comment: I added a full example in the original question

Comment: got it. then you probably have to set the var inline. see updated answer

Comment: Well, I was hoping to find something more elegant, but this works. Surprising this is not supported. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks that this is not possible. I tested with this:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: paramOne
    default: $[lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ',''))]
    type: string
  - name: paramTwo
    default: $(runtimeVar)
    type: string
  - name: paramThree
    default: $(compileVar)
    type: string
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: "Run PowerShell script"
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "${{parameters.paramOne}}"
      Write-Host "${{parameters.paramTwo}}"
      Write-Host "${{parameters.paramThree}}"
```

and

```yaml
trigger: none

variables:
  runtimeVar: $[lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ',''))]
  compileVar: ${{ lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ','')) }}

pool:
  vmImage: windows-2019

steps:
- template: parameter-with-default-runtime-template.yml
```

and I got:

```
$[lower(replace(variables['System.TeamProject'],' ',''))]
devopsmanual
devopsmanual
```

So you see, the same syntax which is used to populate variable doesn't do the same when you use it as default for parameter.